# Как отменить стандартное действий клавиш в браузере?

Tags: javascript

event.preventDefault(); Не отменяет стандартное действие клавии space скролл страницы, как отменить стандартное действий space

Comment: Возможно ты добавлял обработчик не на тот элемент

Comment: Сделайте страницу без скролла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559830/html-prevent-space-bar-from-scrolling-page). `e.target == document.body` используется для того, чтобы у пользователей была возможность добавлять пробелы в поля ввода.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 32 && e.target == document.body) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
body { height: 10000px; }
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: keyListener.keyDown(window, function(event) {})

Comment: keyListener.keyDown(window, function(event) {event.preventDefault() }) Не отменяет при такой функции space

Answer (score 1):

Все отменяет. Используя [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events) я узнал код клавиши **space**.

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 500vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: зачем использовать jquery?

Comment: @ЭльдарГучеренко, можно и без..